# TwoLineListItem - Custom attributes

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I override the XML attributes of TwoLineListItem. I don't want to do it Java. I'm trying to make the backgrounds of the view and the textViews transparent, but it isn't working when I do it in Java.

setBackGroundDrawable
setBackGroundColor
setBackGroundResource

These don't seem to do what I need them to do. I've tried making no background. I've tried setting an alpha value of 0 to the color, but I still get the same old white list boxes. I have a drawable background that is behind the TwoLineListItem view, and thats all I want to show for the background, not the Item background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding of your question you are trying to make your TextView's background to trasparent. this is what i use to do this:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textviewID);
 tv.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

And I didn't get your point about TwoLineListItem. But if you want it to become single line, then write in xml properties of your TextView:

```
android:singleLine="true"
```

If this was not the question then please elaborate a bit.

Comment: TwoLineListItem is a custom view, not a simple textView. Also, android:singleLine="true" is a deprecated property

Comment: Thanks.  I actually just made my own custom TwoLineListItem layout.  I just needed to have <TwoLineListItem at the top (instead of RelativeLayout, etc.) and i had to set android:mode="twoLine"